# How pass $http,$scope by require?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.controller('Ctrlajax', ['$scope', 'version','$sce', '$resource', '$http',
  function ($scope, version,$sce,$resource,$http) {
    $scope.answer  = 'Ожидание ответа от сервера.....';
    require('ajax_module');
}])
```

**ajax_module.js**

```
define('ajax_module',['angular'],function($http){
   var path = './././data/' 
   $http.get(path+'res.php').success(function(data){
      debugger
      $scope.answer = data;
   });
})
```

Error:Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
How to pass $scope,$http?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what are you trying to do. But since you are already injected $http services in your controller, you can directly use is in controller.

```
     .controller('Ctrlajax', ['$scope', 'version','$sce', '$resource',
      '$http',function ($scope, version,$sce,$resource,$http) {
              $scope.answer  = 'Ожидание ответа от сервера.....';
              $http.get(path+'res.php').success(function(data){
                $scope.answer = data;
              });

       }])
```

If you want to separate the logic, use custom services instead of require. Then inject the services to your controller to use it.